# Refresh or regenerate HttpContext.Session.SessionID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to refresh or regenerate the `HttpContext.Session.SessionID`?

I am using this (browser) SessionID to follow a customer sign up of a certain product.

I use this ID to track their movement and errors and progression along the page.

After the user signs up, I want to refresh the session id, to let them theoretically sign up twice.

But i need the new ID to make it a new independent sign up.

Comment: For what purpose?  This sounds like a classic example of needing to take a step back and address the actual problem rather than continue attempting what you think should be the solution.

Comment: I don't see how "refreshing the session id" would let a user "sign up twice", or how not doing so would prevent it.  What does "sign up" involve?  That sounds like where you should be focusing your effort.  If this "sign up" process is tightly coupled with the session ID then it should be decoupled from it.  Use an identifier that you can control.

Comment: So you want to discard the current session id at some point, e.g. sign up, and cause the system to generate a new session id so that future page views will accrue to a new "user"?

Comment: @HABO you are correct

Comment: @David, you have a point, but I need them coupled.

Comment: @Pinch: You absolutely do not *need* them coupled.  Perhaps you *want* them coupled because you're convinced it makes things easier or because you don't want to expend the effort to de-couple them.  While I hope you can get this to work, perhaps with the answer posted below, understand that *choosing* to tightly couple things is, in fact, your choice and not an architectural necessity.

Comment: @David SessionID "Apple" logs to my database saying that the propective customer clicked on A B C, Now the user goes ahead for a second sign up in the same browser but attempts to click on A and fails with and exception.  Remember that these are not Real customers yet, they are only identified via the Session

Comment: @David, I am now reconsidering, you do have a valid point and I thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Here is what I did and it produces a new session id:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblSession.Text = Session.SessionID;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
}
```

If you abandon the session, then the next page request will receive a new session id.

Comment: That won't refresh the SessionID

Comment: I thought i tried that allow me a second go at it..stay tuned.

Comment: Nope, sorry stays the same: var q = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
            HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
            var q1 = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
            HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
            var q2 = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
            HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
            var q3 = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
            HttpContext.Session.Abandon();

Comment: @Pinch - I believe that if you abandon the session, then the _next_ page request will receive a new session id.

Comment: you do realize that you need to actually reload a page for it to work... you cannot just do it in a single call... That is why I have a label and a button on my page to achieve that, so clicking of the button progresses me to the next page.